# Why is the following equality involving big $O$-notation true?

Tags: calculus, inequality, analytic-number-theory

Suppose I know that $\Delta(x)$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\Delta(x) = O(\sqrt{x}).$ Suppose that $x$ is a large real number and that $h < x/2.$ Given this, why does the equality
$$\dfrac{x \log{x} + (2\gamma-1)x+\Delta(x)}{h}-\dfrac{(x-h)\log{x-h}+(2\gamma-1)(x-h)+\Delta(x-h)}{h}$$
$$= \log(x) + 2\gamma + O(\frac{h}{x})+O(\frac{x^{1/2}}{h})$$ hold? Here $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: $\frac{\Delta(x)-\Delta(x-h)}{h} = O(\frac{x^{1/2}}{h})$ and you are supposed to say $\Delta$ is the error term in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function#Dirichlet's_divisor_problem

Comment: @reuns The term I was having trouble explaining was $O(h/x),$ not the $O(x^{1/2}/h).$ Do you have a quick way to deduce this error term?

Comment: $\log x - \log (x-h) =  -\log(1-h/x) = O(h/x)$